# How to start two services on boot up in android

Tags: android, service

Right now I have one service running on boot up. In the similar way I tried creating an other service class and receiver class.

I am not sharing my code as one of my service is running on boot up in right matter so tried implementing in same way

Is it the right way of doing or do I need to do anything extra for running two services?

Comment: Have you run into any problems doing it this way?

Comment: why have two receivers?

Comment: I was using two receivers and starting start up the services in different receiver. Is that wrong?

Comment: @user1810931 Yes, if both Receivers respond to the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast and all they do is start a Service, you can just start both Services from one Receiver.